# How to delete a QGraphicsItem in a PlotItem by mouse click on it

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyqtgraph

If the top module is a pg.GraphicsScene, it can work properly, when a rect is added to the scene, it can be selected by the itemAt() and removed from the scene. But when the top module is a pg.GraphicsLayoutWidget, with a PlotItem is added by addPlot, then the rect is added to the PlotItem, now the itemAt() returns a QGraphicsRectItem seems to be some of background things but not point to the added rect, if perform the deletion, this QGraphicsRectItem is to be deleted first, then the added rect can be selected, the reason why and what is the QGraphicsRectItem background at the top selection level? Any help will be appreciated very much!

```
import sys
import pyqtgraph as pg
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtGui
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QGraphicsRectItem
pg.setConfigOption('background', 'k')
pg.setConfigOption('foreground', 'w')

rect1 = QGraphicsRectItem(120, 120, 60, 60)
rect1.setPen(pg.mkPen((51, 51, 153), width=2))
rect1.setBrush(pg.mkBrush(51, 51, 153, 50))

rect2 = QGraphicsRectItem(200, 200, 80, 80)
rect2.setPen(pg.mkPen((51, 51, 153), width=2))
rect2.setBrush(pg.mkBrush(51, 51, 153, 50))

rect1.setFlag(rect1.ItemIsFocusable)
rect1.setFlag(rect1.ItemIsSelectable)
rect2.setFlag(rect2.ItemIsFocusable)
rect2.setFlag(rect2.ItemIsSelectable)

rect1.setZValue(1000)
rect2.setZValue(1000)

class win(pg.GraphicsLayoutWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle('pyqtgraph GraphicsLayoutWidget')

        self.plt1 = self.addPlot(title='pyqtgraph PlotItem')
        self.plt1.setEnabled(False)

        self.plt1.addItem(rect1)
        self.plt1.addItem(rect2)
        self.plt1.disableAutoRange()

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        #item = self.scene().itemAt(event.pos(), QtGui.QTransform())
        item = self.itemAt(event.pos())
        print(item)
        #self.plt1.removeItem(item)
        self.scene().removeItem(item)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = win()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, You want to remove rectangle, but nothing else.
In Your current implementation, You are removing everything You click on and You would have to implement some logic to detect **"is this the item I want to remove"** ?

Instead You can create new Class `RemovableRect`, which indicates that it can be removed from the Scene `onMousePressEvent`.
And You can follow same logic for other items with same behavior.

Here is modified code using such a removable rectangle:

```
import sys

import pyqtgraph as pg
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QGraphicsRectItem

pg.setConfigOption('background', 'k')
pg.setConfigOption('foreground', 'w')


class RemovableRect(QGraphicsRectItem):

    def mousePressEvent(self, event: 'QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent') -> None:
        """Remove me from the Scene"""
        self.scene().removeItem(self)


rect1 = RemovableRect(120, 120, 60, 60)
rect1.setPen(pg.mkPen((51, 51, 153), width=2))
rect1.setBrush(pg.mkBrush(51, 51, 153, 50))

rect2 = RemovableRect(200, 200, 80, 80)
rect2.setPen(pg.mkPen((51, 51, 153), width=2))
rect2.setBrush(pg.mkBrush(51, 51, 153, 50))

rect1.setFlag(rect1.ItemIsFocusable)
rect1.setFlag(rect1.ItemIsSelectable)
rect2.setFlag(rect2.ItemIsFocusable)
rect2.setFlag(rect2.ItemIsSelectable)


class win(pg.GraphicsLayoutWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle('pyqtgraph GraphicsLayoutWidget')

        self.plt1 = self.addPlot(title='pyqtgraph PlotItem')

        self.plt1.addItem(rect1)
        self.plt1.addItem(rect2)
        self.plt1.disableAutoRange()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = win()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I removed few lines from Your code, especially `self.plt1.setEnabled(False)` which would disable event propagation to Your rectangles.

Comment: Thanks！After adopting your method, I creat the removable RECT class, it can be selected by mouse click and then removed by press "delete" key.